# Games on Steam do not launch

Tags: drivers, graphics, ati, games, steam

I got through various problems to make Steam launch.. with my AMD Radeon R7 4 GB Graphics card and the XOrg (Gallium) Graphics, (I can't login, Login Loop happens, and I can't do CTRL + ALT + F1 / F2, because I will get stuck into a black screen, if I use fglxr)

**See this thread first: https://askubuntu.com/questions/666326/an-x-error-occured-after-attempting-to-launch-steam-on-ubuntu-15-04?noredirect=1#comment962342_666326**

After disabling some files at Steam Runtime, now I can launch Steam. But I cannot launch any game (I think) in it, like Unturned.

Is there a way to fix this?

(Ubuntu 15.04 x64 User)

Comment: I am a Dota 2 player and I have no problem playing it on Linux. Some games are better optimized for Linux while others are not. Google around and check if your game has good Linux compatibility.  And how did you instLl that game?  Did you do a restore from a backup? If so, was it really a Steam for Linux backup and not a windows backup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, try to see if any other games apart from Unturned don't work (Unturned is a dodgy game on Linux)

If that's the case, reinstall Steam, so you have a fresh new version of the library.

Comment: I will try other games.. BRB

Comment: Erm.. first off. Steam crashes on Big Screen mode. sometimes

Second. Valve ignored me completely.

Third.. let me check if any games work

Unturned still doesn't work

Comment: @PanV Any success?